# How to install deb package in aws codebuild worker container

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, dockerfile, aws-codebuild

I'm trying to build docker container and push to to ECR repository. All is working fine locally, but once moved to AWS I'm getting error:

```
dpkg-deb: error: 'docker-ce_20.10.3_3-0_ubuntu-bionic_amd64.deb' is not a Debian format archive
dpkg: error processing archive docker-ce_20.10.3_3-0_ubuntu-bionic_amd64.deb (--install):
dpkg-deb --control subprocess returned error exit status 2
```

from following commands in Docker file:

```
COPY docker-assets/docker-ce_20.10.3_3-0_ubuntu-bionic_amd64.deb /home/folder/
RUN dpkg -i docker-ce_20.10.3_3-0_ubuntu-bionic_amd64.deb
```

Can anyone hit the same issue / help me out ?

Comment: Can you explain what is your image version? What is your buidspec.yml?

Answer (score 0):

I did workaround this with [URL](https://developpaper.com/ubuntu-18-04-simple-installation-of-docker/)